# Calling getActivity() inside a Fragment returns null

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

excuse the trouble I was trying to make a listview for parsing a page for my app, I'll explain: I have a actionbar formed by Fragment.
When instazia the fragment, opening the app the first time "getActivity" does not return null, is the next time, when I start the AsyncTask
In the fragment in which I will stop parsing this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:104)
        at com.megadown.megacodownloader.ParsingArrayAdapter.<init>(ParsingArrayAdapter.java:30)
        at com.megadown.megacodownloader.Tab_Search$ParsingPaginaWeb.onPostExecute(Tab_Search.java:264)
        at com.megadown.megacodownloader.Tab_Search$ParsingPaginaWeb.onPostExecute(Tab_Search.java:125)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code Java that refers:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            // dopo che ho eseguito il parsing mostro i dati nella listview

                adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(myActivity, titoli, descrizioni,immagini);
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);



        }
```

If you want I can post the code of the ArrayAdapter.
Thank you in advance

Comment: One or more parameters to the constructor are null references.

Comment: MyActivity is null, but i don't know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure myActivity has the correct value:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Activity myActivity = getActivity();
        adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(myActivity, titoli, descrizioni,immagini);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Next, point is, *you can't be sure that your activity and fragment is still active* in onPostExecute().

For example, the user could have pressed 'back' button or rotated the screen, which would re-create the activites and fragments.

So, the good code is:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Activity myActivity = getActivity();
        if (myActivity==null) return; // Fragment not active anymore, bail out
        adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(myActivity, titoli, descrizioni,immagini);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: For future reference, you can use isAdded() on the Fragment to see if it's added to the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment's getActivity() will only return expectable value while the associated activity has done onCreate method.